# mongoDb - testng for date in aggregation

Tags: mongodb, date, aggregation-framework, conditional-statements

I want to return JUST the year from a date field

so I did this, when I return the full date 
(Note: this is part of aggregation where the 'joined' array of objects is being unwound - so I can't just refer to 'date_joined'))

```
$project: {
    _id:0,
    user_id: '$_id',
    date_joined: '$joined.date_joined',
    date_joined: { $year:'$joined.date_joined' }
}
```

that might work great if I were requiring a date to be put in - but for the case at hand, there may NOT be a date - the field may be empty...it is actually a "STRING" field - so this may complicate things.

so I get this error

```
Assert: command failed: {
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1561736842, 1),
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "can't convert from BSON type string to Date",
    "code" : 16006,
    "codeName" : "Location16006"
} : aggregate failed
```

Then I tried to do a $cond, if my data was a type 9 (date) return the year, otherwise return a blank string

```
$project: {
    _id:0,
    user_id: '$_id',
    date_joined: '$joined.date_joined',
    date_joined: {
    $cond: { 
        if: { 'joined.date_joined': { $type : 9 } }, 
        then: { $year:'$joined.date_joined' }, 
        else: '' 
        }
    }
}
```

I may have gotten the syntax wrong - but in my IF as it is above (withouth $) I get this error

```
"errmsg" : "FieldPath field names may not contain '.'.",
```

if I add a $

```
if: { '$joined.date_joined': { $type : 9 } }
```

I get this error

```
"errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$joined.date_joined'"
```

So I am stuck - I want to return the YEAR only of a date (if it's a date) and basically ignore it if it's not a date...

After posting, I went to confirm type of field in model, and it is string, not date - so doing a type check wont work...this may be an issue of converting a string to a date - then taking the year.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work as:

```
$cond: { 
     if: { $ne : ['$joined.date_joined',''] }, 
     then: { $year: { $toDate: '$joined.date_joined' } }, 
     else: '' 
}
```